# QThread: safe way of modifying a variable from different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I am new to QThread and multithreading, so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. The program has not crashed so far, but I want to check if I am doing it correctly. I have some code as follows (MyThreadClass is inherited from QThread):

```
std::vector<MyThreadClass* > workThreads;
for(int i=0;i<Solutions.size();i++)
{
    workThreads.push_back(new MyThreadClass(Solutions[i]));
}
for(int i=0;i<workThreads.size();i++)
{
    connect(workThreads[i], SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinished()));
    workThreads[i]->start();
}

bool finished = false;
while(!finished)
{
    if(m_finishedThread==workThreads.size())
        finished=true;

    this->msleep(10);
}
```

The onFinished function is given as follows:

```
void MyClass::onFinished()
{
    ++m_finishedThread;
}
```

So you can see that the while loop is waiting for all the threads to finish and updated the m_finishedThread variables. Is this a safe way of doing it? If all threads finish their job and trying to "connect" to onFinished() function, will it cause a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's safe. The trick is that the connection you will establish between your QThread subclasses and `this` will be a *queued* connection. That's because the thread that emits the signal `finished` (*) is different from the thread `this` (the receiver) lives in.

A **queued connection** is implemented via event posting. A special event is posted to the event queue of the thread `this` lives in; the handling of that event is calling your slot. So, your slot will only be accessed

1. sequentially
2. from one thread only: the one `this` lives in

and that's obviously thread safe.

By the way, is that your real code? You could do exactly the same with

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) 
    threads[i]->wait();
```

---

(*) I'm talking about the thread which *emits* the signal, not the affinity of the object that emits the signal. In particular, chances are that your QThread subclass objects are living in the very same thread than `this`!

Where's the catch? The thread which emits `finished` is not the one those objects (and `this`) are living in -- is the thread *managed* by those objects.

---

**Addendum (2)**: [this](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#3448) is the code that implements signal emission. As you can see, the check is against *the thread currently running* vs. *the thread the receiver lives in*. The thread the sender lives in is not taken into account, so you **don't** need to do stuff like `thread->moveToThread(thread)` to make a queued connection.

How's it possible that the thread currently running isn't the same thread the sender lives in? Because that's exactly what QThread does: the QThread object lives in one thread, the thread it manages (and which emits `finished()`!) is another thread:

```
// runs in the MANAGED thread; lives in any thread
void QThread::run_in_another_thread() {
    run(); // user-supplied implementation
    emit finished();
}
```

**Addendun to the addendum**: but then, are you relying on the undocumented knowledge that `finished` gets emitted from another thread? Isn't that relying on the implementation?

The answer is **no**. There's only one other choice: `finished()` gets emitted as part of a reaping/cleanup handling, coming from the event loop the QThread object is leaving. That is, the same thread `this` is living in.

It can't come from anywhere else -- if we're running user code, we aren't running anything else (remember that *one* thread can't be running *two* different things).

That implies:

1. That you have a running event loop in the thread `this` lives in. You need this in any case.
2. That the invokation will be "direct" (i.e. direct call), because the thread emitting the signal is the same one `this` lives in. So, we're just calling a function *within the same thread*; by definition, that's thread safe.

So, this changes absolutely nothing about the way we handle this. It requires an active event loop in `this`, and that's it.

---

**Addendum**: I should've read the code better. This doesn't change what I said above, but:

```
bool finished = false;
while(!finished)
{
    if(m_finishedThread==workThreads.size())
        finished=true;

    this->msleep(10);
}
```

This loop here never returns to the event loop. This means your slot will never be invoked because the metacall events will never be processed. Please use a `QTimer` or sneak in some calls to `QCoreApplication::processEvents` instead of this kind of loops!

Comment: but the OP isn't creating a queued connection.

Comment: Yes, (s)he is. I explained why.

Comment: In this case, it is required to explicitly make a Qt::QueuedConnection, but the code doesn't specify the connection type. This means the connection will be of type Qt::AutoConnection, which in turn defaults to Qt::DirectConnection because the thread affinity of MyThreadClass is the main thread, since moveToThread() was not called. So the code will not be thread-safe because the slot will be executed from within the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on connection part. I'm not sure if threads[i]->wait() will give what I want to do. I am trying to have computation running on separate thread to speed up the processing time. What I forgot to put in is that each thread will take a different "Solution[i]" value to give different results. And all results are written to a vector (with mutex guarding it).

Comment: @VíctorFernández: again, no. You're assuming that the choice looks at the affinity of the QThread object vs. `this`. That's not the case, and I explained why.

Comment: @peppe Sorry that I couldn't quite understand your suggestion for the Addendum part. Can you give me some example how I should change the code to? The while loop I have aims to stop the program from continuing until all threads have finished the execution. But certainly it doesn't look that good.

Comment: Just change it to the `wait`, as I said. or shove a call to `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` inside that loop, but it's bad pracitce. Read up on http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not subclass `QThread` directly. See:
https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

Create a normal class instead (a subclass of `QObject` or similar) and implement your code there. Then use `moveToThread()` to move the subclass to that thread.

It is safe to connect signals to slots in your object using a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, as long as the passed parameters are not objects and you are not calling methods on those objects without any synchronization mechanism.

Anyway, what you want to do is probably easier to implement using `QtConcurrent`.

Comment: I completely agree that QThread should not be inherited, unless you want to change the underlying threading implementation. However, there seems to be doubt about the future of QtConcurrent. See here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/7942

Comment: It is perfectly legal to subclass QThread depending the situation (Single call long running operation is an example to subclass QThread, i.e. Image Recognition and Processing). As for short independant actions qt::concurrent is more fitting, while permanent running threads should be implemented as a Object residing in QThread.

Comment: Yes, it is legal and sometimes the best option, but 95% of the times it is misused. That's why I think in general it should not be subclassed, unless you're 100% sure you're doing it right.

Comment: @SebastianLange, I disagree with you about when to subclass QThread. QThread is not a thread at all, but actually a thread controller and should only be subclassed if you want to change the way in which the thread is being handled (controlled). It's not designed to be subclassed to add tasks to run on the thread. Note that even the Qt architects claim this and state that the Qt examples are wrong!

Comment: This is kind of a personal view. Generally the given post "youre doing it wrong" started some kind of anti-thread-subclassing movement. But it is still prefered in some situations to subclass QThread, since it creates less overhead and easier blocking operations. This should only be done when no event queue is needed. Most of the time you would not have to subclass QThread, but there are still situations you want QThread to be subclassed. There is also a anti-anti-thread-subclass post: http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html

Answer (score 1):

I probably would not run the while(!finished) loop, since this hangs your mainthread (or executing thread of the while loop). Instead check in onFinished() for running threads and emit a signal when everything is finished.

If you need to wait for all threads to be finished there is still wait()-Condition.

For modifying a variable you can use a Qt:QueuedConnection with a signal to modify a variable if it is not directly accesible.

Be careful with accessing variables from multiple threads directly. It is very often a good idea to use a QMutex when accessing the same variable from different threads.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. One thing I forgot to mention is that all the code is actually running on another separate thread. That is why I don't mind having a while loop blocking the execution (even though it may not be a good practice).

Answer (score 0):

At first sight I'd say no. Indeed, you've connected your threads `finished()` signal without specifying the last parameter of connect (which is the [ConnectionType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) )

As you can see from the documentation, if you don't specify this parameter, `Qt::AutoConnection` is the default one, and specify that the program will behave differently if the signal comes from an object in the same thread, or in a different thread.

In this case, `Qt::QueuedConnection` will be used for these calls, which means that when the signal will trigger a call to the slot, this call be queued in the event loop of the receiving thread. If multiple thread finish at the same time, calls to `onFinished()` will be queued, and invoked one by one.

EDIT: In addition, I suggest you consider a different approach for your design based on thread, and read [this](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) which says you should rather create a worker object and then move it to the thread.

Comment: To nitpick: there's no "default to" -- the type gets chosen on a per-emission basis.

Comment: @peppe What I meant was that in his case, Qt would choose QueuedConnection for these calls.

Answer (score -2):

nop, seems ok, Qt's signal/slots system is thread safe, actually, when a signal is emitted, it's put at the end of a queue, and is processed by the main event loop in that order.

Comment: Be careful. You can totally have thread unsafe code with Qt signal/slot system if you don't pay attention...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @JBL can you give me a thread unsafe situation for the QT signal/slot system?

Comment: That's just false. Depends on the connection type.

Comment: @JohnYang Simple : connect a signal from some thread to a slot of some other thread, and use `Qt::DirectConnection` as connection type : you may have thread-unsafe code now.